# Meaning of 気分的に

Tags: grammar

The person is describing (making up excuses) as to why they were late and one of them they said the below:

「いやぁ……参りましたなぁ……コンビニの店員がちんたらレジやるから遅刻ですよ……」

私は時計を見る。

時間は11時すぎ、だいたい四時限目がはじまるぐらい。

「えーと、それと電車がちんたらしてたからかなぁ？……**なんか気分的に**……」

それでもあまり時間は合わない……。

「……あと……シャワーがちんたら出てたとか……**なんか気分的に**……」

「……なんとなくそういう理由かな？」

How exactly does this 気分的に change the meaning of the sentence? I'm assuming it is trying to convey the idea of 'feeling' like the train was moving sluggishly but I'm not sure how this differs from conveying the information using some form of e.g. ような気がする

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. It *may* mean "...or so I feel", but before concluding this we need to exclude other possibilities. Maybe you've missed some context around this. Please share several sentences surrounding this.

Comment: added a bit more of the surrounding lines

Answer (score 3):

It's adding an acknowledgment that the slower pace of the train is actually not real (and is merely imagined).

If one is really trying to make excuses, one wouldn't do this (because it nullifies the excuse). The speaker is either comically cocky, making fun of the conversation partner, or is being sheepish (my bet would be the former two, given the choice of ちんたら which doesn't fit with being sheepish).

The cliche would then be for the conversation partner to reply 「お前、おちょくってんのか！」、「こいつ、大物だな」 etc.